# It is possible to gain rep past your rep cap through a bug/loophole

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I discovered that you can still gain rep after you have crossed the rep cap ***without having your answer accepted.***

I downvoted an answer, and then undid my downvote later when they edited, and I noticed this. So I did something to confirm my suspicion.

#### Step 1

*Hit your rep cap.* You can see I've already hit mine today:

[image]

#### Step 2

Find a random answer and downvote/un-downvote a few times.

#### Step 3

Wait for someone to upvote you. This particular answer of mine got upvoted within a few seconds, so I was able to capture this:

[image]

I'm 99.9% sure this is something that shouldn't happen, and I'm not sure if this is a known issue but I believe it is something the moderators must be aware of.

I am absolutely fine with losing the reputation that I've gained during this experiment.

I would like to propose a solution: *Prevent the up/down vote button from being clickable more than 1-2 times between edits.*

Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: +1 for cleverness, but as Servy points out, rep gained from this doesn't last.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thankfully... ^^;

Comment: You didn't actually gain rep. If you go to our `/reputation` audit you'll see your rep didn't actually go up. There is some heavy caching going on on your daily rep that has some edge-case issues (*bugs*), and undoing a downvote after the rep-cap is one of them.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, I can't hit the rep cap.

Comment: Eventual consistency FTW

Comment: +1 for a very well thought out and excellently documented question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will be corrected when a rep recalc happens.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. How often does it happen? On the hour? Every 10 minutes?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Certain types of actions trigger it.  I think it also happens once a day, if memory serves.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: different things trigger it. Deletion of content you received rep for is one of them, and so is undeletion. In the past I've sometimes had somewhat persistent off-by-cache errors stick around for a few days.

Comment: @Servy It doesn't. ;) It's too expensive to just recalc every profile every day for no reason.

Comment: Thanks all, for the clarification!